# Set the Color of a Google Calendar event with the API in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-core, google-calendar-api

i have a question regarding the Google Calendar API with C#. I want to set the color of an specific event but whatever i add to the ColorId property, it does not affect my event after updating.

Here ist my code:

```
 Event data = CalendarService.Events.Get("primary", id).Execute();
 data.Description = _GetDescription(done, notes, uniqueLinkId);

 Colors colors = CalendarService.Colors.Get().Execute();
 if (colors != null && colors.Calendar != null)
 {
      var color = colors.Calendar.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Value.Background == "#16a765");
      if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(color.Key))
      {
                data.ColorId = color.Key;
      }
 }

 var request = CalendarService.Events.Update(data, "primary", id);
 request.SupportsAttachments = true;
 request.SendNotifications = false;

 request.Execute();
```

Any ideas on how this doesn't work?

Regards,
Andreas

Comment: check data what is the color id it has now?   and what color id are you trying to set it to?  You might want to look at the patch method btw.

Comment: Hi, @DaImTo the color id of data is "4" and i want to set it to "8". What do you mean with the patch method? Thanks, Andreas

Comment: I am not even getting it back its like the colorid returns null all the time.

Comment: When i fetch the event after updating, the ColorId is "8". That is correct. But when i look in my google calendar, the event still has the same color as before updating. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like its might be a bug [CalendarList background color change is not working (.NET)](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36755566)

The only issue with this is that i have not been able to get it to set using the Google APIs exporer either. which makes me wonder if this is something they removed after the release of the new Google calendar.

I have sent off an email to Google but i dont have a direct contact on that team it make be a while before i hear anything.

Comment: Thank you for your efforts. I am looking forward to hear from you, if you get any answers :)